# My admin backend wont open with Typo3

Tags: apache-http-server, php, administrator, cms, typo3

Im on the Admin Tools Page of Typo3 and I want to open the admin backend to the website I have so I click the according button ([Admin Page Typo3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECmgH.png)). However all that shows up is the website itself without the backend admin functions.
I'm running Windows 10, XAMPP v3.2.4, Typo3 v9.5.9 and PHP v7.3.9.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I have already tried to navigate there manually by inserting "/typo3" right before the file name.